# Error 1004 application defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba

Here the code:

```
Sub deleterow2()
Dim a As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim c As Integer

LastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For n = 0 To LastRow
a = 1
c = 0
Do Until c = 1
Cells(n + a, 6).Select
If Selection.value = Cells(n, 6) And Selection.value > 30 Then
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Else
c = 1
End If
a = a + 1
Loop
Next n
End Sub
```

What s wrong with that?

Comment: (1) Learn to indent your code (2) Which line errors?

Comment: `n = 0`, which means you are trying to select a range at row 0, hence the error (there is no range at row 0).

Comment: Try to avoid using selection wherever possible - it's good practice and covers any issues that could arise from a user clicking a different cell while the macro is running... `If Cells(n+a, 6).Value = Cells(n, 6).Value And Cells(n+a, 6).Value > 30 Then Cells(n+a, 6).EntireRow.Delete  ...`   FYI it is also good practice to get in the habit of using Option Explicit and `Dim n As Long` etc for the variables.

Comment: I m not familiar with this vba. Can you help rewriting the code?

Comment: During the first iteration, when `n=0` this `Cells(n, 6)` will give you an error, because the rows index begins from 1.

Comment: @DarXyde has your problem, but when deleting rows you should loop backwards to avoid skipping rows. Not sure I follow what you're doing.

Comment: @SJR you are correct.. in all honesty, I've just rewrote the code to get it running, but probably should have tried to improve it as well i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below corrected code... instead of starting `n` at 0, start with `a` at 0. Plus, avoid using `.Select` everything... and you should try to declare your ranges fully:

```vb
Sub deleterow222()

Dim lastRow As Long, R As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim idColumn as Long: idColumn = 6
Dim diffColumn as Long: diffColumn = 19

    lastRow = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For R = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        With ws
            If .Cells(R, idColumn) = .Cells(R - 1, idColumn) And .Cells(R, diffColumn) > 30 Then
                .Cells(R, idColumn).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next R

End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194262/discussion-on-answer-by-darxyde-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined).

Answer (score 1):

Some Tips:

1. You could not use `n = 0` because you will create an error. Rows start from 1.
2. When you loop in order to delete you start from the end.
   `For n = LastRow To 1 Step -1`
3. If there are a lot of lines and you will use `For Loop` declare you variable `As Long`.
4. If you have a lot of rows it s better to use an `Array`.
5. Try to avoid `.Select` by creating a `With Statement` with the sheet name
   `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` and refer to cell using `.Cells(n + A, 6).Value`
6. `Do Until` should start also from high to low due to the fact that you go from bottom to top.

Comment: Can u please write it down for me because it seems that s not working. I m trying to delete successive duplicate with more than 30 min of difference in time.

Comment: please upload an image of you data and the output you want?

Comment: a table ordered by date. in the colum 6 i have the ID and in the colum 10 I have the difference between the date and the previous. I want to delete all the successive rows that have the same ID and their difference is more than 30

Comment: @Error1004 This would have been a much better answer... it just needs someone to understand it as well. Also i like your username lol.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8lh5.png)

Sub deleterow2()

Dim lastRow As Long, R As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

```
lastRow = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For R = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    With ws
        If .Cells(R, 6).value = .Cells(R - 1, 6) And .Cells(R, 19).value > 30 Then
            .Cells(R, 6).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
Next R
```

End Sub

Comment: Should have left the columns to be visible...  you've mentioned before column 6 (`F`) and column 10 (`J`)... Although in your screenshot column 6 (`codall`) looks like it could be an ID column, the column 10 (`lineaagv`) does not look like you would have values of `>30` ... can you please explain again, using column names?

Comment: I was using random numbers. But now you can see properly: when codall is equal to codall in the next row I want that it check if the difference (in colum S) is bigger than 30. If it is bigger then delete the row

Comment: once delete the row it should stay in the same row and check if the new near row ... same thing